# Using name in dropdown

Tags: python, html, django

i want to use the dropdown menu in the request POST query, but I cannot define the name for the dropdown menu options, how can I do this? Is there a chance to do if else according to value with POST in this query?

my ex. view;

```
def list(request):
    if 'Storefront' in request.POST:
        filtre=Alarmlar.objects.filter( Ekip__contains="Storefront" )
    elif 'CAC' in request.POST:
        filtre=Alarmlar.objects.filter ( Ekip__contains="Cac")
    else:
        filtre=Alarmlar.objects.all()
    members_list=filtre
    paginator = Paginator(members_list, 100)
    page = request.GET.get('page')
    try:
        members = paginator.page(page)
    except PageNotAnInteger:
        members = paginator.page(1)
    except EmptyPage:
        members = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)
    return render(request, 'list.html', {'members': members})
```

html;

```
<select class="form-control" id="adsoyad" name="adsoyad" style="text-align:center" required>
<option value="" disabled selected >Choose...</option>
<option value="all">ALL</option>
<option value="Cac">Cac</option>
<option value="Storefront">Storefront</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The name is `adsoyad`, since you specified `<select name="adsoyad" …>`. You thus filter with:

```
def list(request):
    data = request.POST.get('adsoyad')
    if data == 'Storefront':
        filtre=Alarmlar.objects.filter( Ekip__contains="Storefront" )
    elif data == 'Cac':
        filtre=Alarmlar.objects.filter ( Ekip__contains="Cac")
    else:
        filtre=Alarmlar.objects.all()
    members_list=filtre
    paginator = Paginator(members_list, 100)
    page = request.GET.get('page')
    try:
        members = paginator.page(page)
    except PageNotAnInteger:
        members = paginator.page(1)
    except EmptyPage:
        members = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)
    return render(request, 'list.html', {'members': members})
```

Comment: My purpose here is to filter the list by options value, but I cannot run the query because I cannot define a name for <option name="storefront" value="Cac">Cac</option> options. When I define a name to button, the query runs successfully.

Comment: @altintash: but you defined a name in the `<select>` tag that wraps the `<option>`s, hence the value will be associated with that name...

Comment: I actually wrote it to show what I wanted to do, sorry for the misunderstanding. Unfortunately it does not support the <options name attribute, is there any other way I can do this?

Comment: @altintash: again, `<option>` has no name, you define the `name` in the `<select>` tag. That is where you associate the name with a value: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/select

Comment: <span class="input-group-text" id="inputGroup-sizing-default">Ad Soyad</span>
                    <select class="form-control" id="adsoyad" name="adsoyad" style="text-align:center" required>
                    <option value="" disabled selected >Choose</option>
            <option name="Storefront" value="Storefront">Storefront</option>
            <option name="Cac" value="Cac">Cac</option>
            </select> its not worked like this, Do you have any other suggestions that I can run with the option value and the POST request?

Comment: @altintash: `print(request.POST)` in your view, there you can see how it associated values to keys, and that way you thus see what data is in the POST request.